# Windows Firewall blocked port - redirect to webpage

Tags: windows-server-2008, redirect, windows-firewall

I have a Windows Server 2008 R2 Stadard VM.

I've learned how to block a port by accessing Windows Firewall With Advanced Security and adding a New Rule.

Is there a way to redirect traffic to a webpage when traffic tries to access a blocked port?

Answer (score 1):

Not really.  Since lots traffic wouldn't be originating from an http client, and would have no idea what to do with a redirect to http.

If the particular port you are trying to filter is related to an http server, then you might want to setup a proxy/filter/web server instead, and configure a useful error page.

Comment: The server will have Squid proxy installed. Forgive my ignorance, but does that mean that it's a proxy server? Can you bump me in the right direction on how find out how to configure an error page?